# google map v3 issue

Tags: google-maps

I have the below code, however the google map is not being fully shown (only the top left part).  See this [screenshot](http://i49.tinypic.com/4iehe9.png). Can anybody help please? Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $hotel->hotel_latitude.','.$hotel->hotel_longtitude; ?>);

            var Options = {
                center:latlng,
                zoom:15,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("ourlocation"),Options);

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:latlng,
                animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
            });

            marker.setMap(map);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add width and height to your div, then it will works fine.

```
<div id="imgFrame" style="width: 800px; height: 900px"></div>
```

Comment: no success, tried it out, however the width and height was already being called via the css. also this is being used in a jquery mobile site.

Answer (score 0):

After your setMap call, try `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`

Answer (score 0):

In one of my project I used google map v3 but issue is resolved by replacing `http://*` instead of `https://*`. So try this.